ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2 Select lines from a road network that are similar to another line layer
I am working on ArcGIS pro 3.1.2. I have two line layers with different information in the table. One is the road network and the other is the Gritting routes. The lines are not overlapping and can have big spaces. Is there a way to select the road network that are along the gritting roads? I tried to create a buffer (10m) surrounding the gritting routes. And clipped the Road Network inside the buffer. But it did not select the entire gritting routes (some roads were not inside). Also some small bits (perpendicular to the buffer) of the Road network were clipped. In the image: Cumberland PMS is the Road Network layer. Gritting_Route_Old_Merge is the Gritting Route (inside the buffer)

Do your datasets have the same coordinate systems? Looks life a datum shift to me? I would double check that first.

I reprojected the gritting route layer. Now they have the same projection.

So do they now overlap as you wanted?
